# Tension due to unequal forces on a massless spring

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, spring, free-body-diagram

When a massless spring is pulled by 5N on both sides the tension in the spring is 5N (proved by considering COM at rest and breaking the spring into two springs of 2k each)...what if the forces applied were 5N at one end and 7N at the other end?What would be the resultant tension in the spring?

Comment: Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Average of 5 and 7 maybe?

Comment: I am not able to find an answer in the duplicate as well!!

Comment: Drawing a free body diagram for the whole spring might help.

Comment: Well I did but since the spring is massless that would mean it has infinte acceleration?

Comment: So what is your conclusion about having a mass spring in this situation?

Comment: @SchwarzKugelblitz Right, but since we can pretend the spring is massless, we can pretend that infinite acceleration isn't really a problem either.  It's also not relevant to the tension, which is what the question concerns.

Comment: A mass spring would probably accelerate because of the excess 2 N and the remaining 5 would show up as tension?

Comment: @SchwarzKugelblitz And that's basically all there is to it.

Comment: Ok what if there is massless spring?

Comment: @SchwarzKugelblitz That has no effect on the tension. You just wouldn't be able to determine the acceleration because it's non-physical.

Comment: It's not possible to pull on the two ends of a massless spring with different tensions.