# Pulling a spring from both ends with different forces

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, spring, string

2 people pulling a spring with equal forces from opposite ends is identical to pulling it from a rigid wall, but how to calculate its extension if its pulled from both ends with different forces? Should the mean of the forces be taken?

Comment: How are you going to apply different forces to the ends of the spring without the sping accelerating away?

Comment: but there would still be an extension in its length right?

Comment: Yes, there will be extension.

Comment: @mikestone I don't think the OP said anything about it not accelerating away. Plus just the center of mass will accelerate, you can still pull on the ends while this happens.

Comment: @BioPhysicist  How does the wall-attached sping have unequal  forces acting on it?

Comment: @mikestone How else would the center of mass move?

Comment: OP, have you tried writing out the equations of motion?

Comment: @VincentThacker That's not the same thing. This question is asking about pulling on each end with a different force.

Comment: @BioPhysicist It is the same thing. In most problems the spring is assumed to be massless, and a massless spring cannot have different forces on each end. There are numerous such questions all over this site, for example [this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/497859/tension-due-to-unequal-forces-on-a-massless-spring) which has itself been marked a duplicate of another.

Comment: @VincentThacker Then perhaps it would be best to first ask the OP if this system is massless.

Comment: Would it matter if the spring is massless or not?

Comment: @HaydenSoares Really what matters is the system. In my answer I do put in mass (to simplify matters, I put it at the ends). That way you can still think of a massless spring. If there is no mass at all then as Vincent points out things get weird.

Comment: The straightforward answer to the massless case is that it is just not possible for there to be different forces on each end. It is [well-explained](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/285708/tension-on-a-massless-string) for massless strings, which are simply massless springs with a very large spring constant. That's all there is to the answer. However when the spring has mass things get a bit more interesting, but in general the spring still moves to a state where the tension is as uniform as possible. See for example [this PDF](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1101.0570)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring force on both sides of spring](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/273829/spring-force-on-both-sides-of-spring)

Answer (score 1):

If we assume Hooke's law holds, then for a spring constant $k$ with resting length $\ell$, the spring force is given by $F=\pm k(x_R-x_L-\ell)$, where $x_R$ and $x_L$ are the positions of the right and left ends of the spring respectively (the $\pm$ sign is to take care of which side of the spring you are looking at).

Now, if you assume identical masses $m$ are attached to each end of the spring, and that a force $F_R$ acts to the right on the right side and a force of $F_L$ acts to the left on the left side, you should be able to use Newton's second law to determine the equations of motion for $x_R$ and $x_L$, and more importantly the equation of motion for the separation $x_R-x_L$ to find where the equilibrium is obtained given $F_R$ and $F_L$.

Comment: I understood the equation 'F=±k(xR−xL−ℓ')' , but I not sure about how  to determine the equations of motion for xR and xL..

Comment: I tried using the 'assuming identical masses idea', F_r - kx = ma, kx - F_l = ma (right and left masses respectively), therefore F_r - kx =kx -  F_l => kx = (F_r + F_l) / 2

Comment: Is what I did above logically right? I assumed that the spring applies equal force on each mass and that the entire system is accelerating uniformly , i.e the extended length of the spring is constant

Comment: @HaydenSoares Yes, that is correct for the equilibrium length $x=x_R-x_L-\ell$

Comment: but does assuming that there are 2 masses at each end not prove the above relation for the general case in which the spring is unconnected to anything?

Comment: @HaydenSoares If the spring isn't connected to anything then how is it being pulled on? Some things to think about 1) In the case of equal masses the mass on either end doesn't matter, as it cancels out. 2) There has to be at least some mass somewhere. If you want, work out the general case with unequal masses, and then do some exploration. Why does the mass on either end matter if $m_R\neq m_L$? What if $m_R\ll m_L$? What if $F_L$ is always restricted to be exactly equal to the spring force? The exploration of this system is a good learning opportunity :)

Comment: with unequal masses, I'm getting kx = (m_lF_r + m_rF_l )/m_r + m_l, which suggests that its extension is different than if there were equal masses, so I guess the answer to my question is that it depends on the masses at each ends as well.

Comment: also, (this may be more suitable as a standalone question), regarding the 'if the spring isn't connected then how is it pulled' point, what is pulling the masses that are pulling the spring? We could keep adding masses but never reach a 'first cause'.